# Why can't I boot into recovery mode?

Tags: recovery-mode, htc-dream

I think I'm actually missing something here still. Everything I read suggests I need to boot into recovery mode as a first step, and that I ought to be able to do that by holding down the "home" key while I'm starting up. Instead I get a bang (!) in a triangle icon with a phone next to it.

Have I skipped a step or is there something wrong with my phone? I know there's something wrong with my phone ... that's why I embarked on this project to begin with. But could that be some how preventing me from booting to recovery mode? Or is the problem a skipped step?

Comment: Al Everett pulled the "T-mobile G1" tag from this post but ... the answer is specific to the G1/Dream. I know better than to restore the tag, but don't lose sight of that detail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edit:** Apparently download and recovery modes are merged for the G1.  Just press Alt-L on your physical keyboard while in Download mode, and Recovery will show up.

---

What you're seeing is **Download Mode**.  The key combination is usually subtly different.  In the case of my phone, it's just a matter of having the phone connected to USB or not.  You should try it with and without USB, as well as removing the battery and doing a fresh boot.  (You can also remove the battery, plug into USB, and reinsert the battery and try).  Also try other keys -- you already know using Back instead gets you to that device info screen.

Comment: Some phones need key combos also, see for example http://www.askvg.com/revealing-3-hidden-secret-modes-in-google-android-mobile-phones/

Answer (score 2):

> Everything I read suggests I need to boot into recovery mode as a first step,

If you're using Samsung Spica (and probably most other Samsung phones, not sure about other phones), the general idea of rooting/installing-custom-rom is that the very first time you flash your ROM, you need to do it in **Download Mode**. This first flashing uses the system that Samsung itself uses.

This first flash will usually install ClockworkMod Custom Recovery, which will replace the phone's original Recovery Mode with a much more featureful version. Once you have ClockworkMod's Recovery, then you can install any ROM in the Clockwork's .zip file format; nearly all (or all?) modded Android are distributed as a Clockwork .zip format.