# G1 Create Image of Current State

Tags: backup, htc-dream

Is it possible to create an image of my phone (G1, cupcake) so that I may revert back to it at a later date?

I'm not scared of using the Android SDK, I only needs the steps to create the file.

Comment: There's a pretty thorough response on https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7168/what-is-the-right-way-to-backup-my-whole-phone with more indispensable information at https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7160/why-cant-i-boot-into-recovery-mode

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I perform a full pre-rooting backup of an Android phone?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5667/how-do-i-perform-a-full-pre-rooting-backup-of-an-android-phone)

Comment: Note the date. This was asked on Super User before an Android Stack Exchange site was even a glimmer.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [nandroid](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=459830) to do this.

If you update your recovery image to [Cyanogen's 1.4 recovery](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=523558) then it has nandroid built in.

These are tools from the community and are not officially tested or supported so make sure you fully understand what you're doing before using them.

Comment: I decided to go with HandyBackup and wiped the phone. I have now installed the recovery correctly and will make a true image once I have th proper setup.

It's a shame there's not a built in function from Google or T-mobile.

Comment: Cyanogen's 1.4 recovery with nandroid is *so* worth it (and easy).

Comment: I completely agree now that I've installed the recovery properly. Already made a back up for when I load new roms.