# Gaining root acces/installing custom rom on G1 with build number CRC1

Tags: htc-dream, rooting, rom-flashing

Could you please share your knowledge about how to flash the latest update of stock Android OS on G1 (aka HTC Dream)? I would like to try out some custom roms, but most information I was able to find relates to the RC30 or R33.

Comment: See also http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-phone and http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1/ive-rooted-my-phone-now-what

Comment: Kamil, A lot of folks are pointing you off site here (XDA, Haykuro) but I wanted to add that if you have specific questions as you go (like ... "how do I boot into recovery mode on the G1" http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7160/why-cant-i-boot-into-recovery-mode)  definitely don't hesitate to bring them here.

Answer (score 3):

I think you will have better luck at the [XDA developers forum](http://forum.xda-developers.com/)

It's the main place for ROM cookers (mainly HTC devices), for the [Dream follow this link](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=446).

Try this thread for more info on [rooting your HTC](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=442480)

Answer (score 2):

I agree with palehorse, Haykuro's blog is very easy to follow and is where I learned the process. Once you are ready for a custom ROM, the best, by far in my opinion, are released by cyanogen. This is mostly due to their very fast speed compared to other ROMS.  You can find the latest, as of me writing this, at: [his post on XDA Developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=539744)

Comment: Agreed, I just updated from JF1.5 ADP to the most recent cyanogen rom (4.0.2 now) and I am loving it.  Automatic apps to SD, swap on SD, and it seems to perform quite a bit better than the official TMO and JF roms.

Answer (score 1):

This [tutorial on Haykuro's blog](http://haykuro.theiphoneproject.org/?page%5Fid=35) was very easy to follow.  I used it up to the point of flashing with the ROM I wanted.